# c# Restful service can not be post by RestSharp.RestClient sometimes

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp

I create a Restful service host by console application, app.config and interface looks like below:

```
   <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
        <client/>
        <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MyAppServiceBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <standardEndpoints/>
        <services>
          <service behaviorConfiguration="MyAppServiceBehavior" name="MyAppService">
            <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="MyAppServiceEndPointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyAppServiceBinding" name="MyAppServiceRESTEndPoint" contract="IMyAppService" kind="" endpointConfiguration=""/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="MyAppServiceMex" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:51920/MyAppService/"/>
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyAppServiceEndPointBehavior">
              <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"
                automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" />
              <dataContractSerializer />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyAppServiceBehavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug />
              <dataContractSerializer />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
      </system.serviceModel>

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyAppService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Set Device Configuration
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="setDeviceConfiguration"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "SetDeviceConfiguration")]
    SetDeviceConfigurationResponse SetDeviceConfiguration(SetDeviceConfiguration setDeviceConfiguration);
}
```

Then create a console to access, but got Bad Request 400.
                RestClient restClient = new RestClient(ServiceUri);

```
            RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(typeof(T).Name, Method.POST);
            restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            restRequest.AddBody(request);

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
            int nLen1 = json.Length;
            int nLen2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json).Length;

            IRestResponse<R> response = restClient.Execute<R>(restRequest);
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw response.ErrorException;
            }
```

The SetDeviceConfiguration is a DataContract, if I new this object with nothing set, the service is be called, but filled data almost 55kb always got Bad Request. If I change Interface to this, It's work.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "SetDeviceConfiguration")]
SetDeviceConfigurationResponse SetDeviceConfiguration(Stream stream);
```

Can someone help? thanks in advance.